# Which .NET framework with MVC 4?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just installed MVC 4 and am looking at using it with VS 2010.  I notice that by default when creating a project the .NET framework is 4.0, yet the example code I am looking at uses framework 4.5.  If I want to utilise all the features of MVC 4 do I need to install framework 4.5, or should 4.0 be enough?

EDIT : Seems like I will go with 4.0, although will 4.5 be the default framework in VS2012?  If so, I would probably prefer to install that to save having to make framework changes later.

Answer (score 22):

Look at the MVC4 [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27419). There is a requirements section saying:

> Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, 
>                                    Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista, Windows XP
>
> .NET 4, ASP.NET 4, Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010 are required 
>       to use certain parts of this feature.

Answer (score 13):

You need .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 at a minimum but CAN use more features with ASP.NET 4.5.

VS2010 will only support framework 4 features, and thus async/await will not be supported.
For those features you need ASP.NET 4.5. This applies to the Web API as well for example this requires 4.5:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/03/async-mashups-using-asp-net-web-api.aspx

A standard controller/view scenario in MVC4 will work in VS2010 on ASP.NET 4.

Comment: So, does it mean that without visual studio 2012 I won't be able to use async/await?

Comment: Well - no and yes - you can use visual studio express, the .NET sdk and do it manually, or check out the async stuff here (disclaimer - not fully sure what's contained and Ive never used it: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983)

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly no need to install 4.5 ([mvc4-release-notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes)). ASP.NET MVC 4 is available for framework version 4.0 as well 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just writing an app as you go then just write and compile. 
That will tell you if you have what you need. Tho:

> Utilise all the features of MVC

does not sound very user-centric ;)

Also do yourself a favor and deploy to IIS as your development server NOT Cassini or whatever its called nowadays.